# Is this a curl POST call?

Tags: curl, post, get

I am using the below URL to download data. I am not sure if its a post call.

```
/app/localapps/curl/bin/curl --cacert /app/ac/certificates/cacert.pem   --proxy-user ABC:XYZ  -F username=***** -F password=**** -F report=Composites -F type=CDS -F version=5 -F family=None  -F format=xml -F date=20181116 https://www.markit.com/export.jsp
```

can someone help with this please? does this qualify as a GET call? what would be the correct URL to use?

Comment: No, curl's `-F` does multi-part POST. Like the manual explains...

Comment: thanks . I was told by one of the guys from the destination that they see only a GET call. I have been emphasizing that its a POST

Comment: add `--trace-ascii dump.txt` to your command line and you'll get a full trace of the request, showing every little detail of it...